# Why doesn't my code use the correct animation?

Tags: animation, game-development, godot, gdscript

I had a functioning fighting game written in Python with movement, frame data, attacks (that didn't work) but no gravity. I'm trying to rewrite it with Godot, but I'm really lost.

I had a system of implementing frame data into my attacks so I could actually transition from idle to attacks and vice versa easily. Right now, my issue is I want to attack and play that animation, but it keeps constantly playing the idle animation. I want to get this one thing working before I start doing hitboxes and collision stuff. Here is my code:

```python
extends KinematicBody2D


export var walking_speed = 100
export var falling_speed = 0
var time = 0
onready var anim = $Sprite
var state = "Idle"

func _ready():
    set_physics_process(true)
    set_process(true)
    $AnimationTree.active = true

func gravity():
    pass

func _physics_process(delta):
    time += delta
    print(time)
    # If you press both A and D, you will stop entirely
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        walking_speed == 0
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/Neutral/current", 0)
    #if you press A or D, you will move left or right accordingly
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        move_and_collide(Vector2(-walking_speed * delta, 0))
        anim.flip_h = true
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/Neutral/current", 1)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        move_and_collide(Vector2(walking_speed * delta, 0))
        anim.flip_h = false
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/Neutral/current", 1)
    else:
        walking_speed = walking_speed

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Horizontal"):
        $AnimationTree.set("parameters/Neutral/current", 2)
```

This code is basically just a mishmash of a bunch of tutorials of things I was told to do (Like for instance, I was told not use `AnimatedSprite` and instead use `AnimationTree`, but it seems the code is a lot more complicated and is just giving me the same problems as last time). If you need me to, I can also post my Python code as well, but it's a giant mess with no comments on it at all.

Comment: THAT IS NO PYTHON. That is GDScript. The syntax is similar to python, but the semantics are closer to Java. Thus, if you had some Python code that you want to copy over to Godot, chances are it does not work. Well, unless you go install the Python language addon. And yes you will get more people looking at the question by using the python tag. And people may come and answer as if it were Python, which means sometimes the answers work and sometimes they don't. What we need is more people answering GDScript questions, not more people posting GDScript questions as tagged as Python.

Comment: I know it's not python. I didn't see there was a GDScript tag, my bad.

but the idea still stays the same. Just in case I need to post my python code to know what I'm going for

Comment: The code can be made much simpler. I have a partially written answer that does the same thing with less code… However, what are the problems you are trying to fix? Because, as I said, what I have does the same thing, so no problem fixed.

Comment: I actually just figured out the issue haha. I was wondering about how to add frame data. I basically just found it out because I saw from a post that _process() is called every frame, so I just did var frame = 0, then under _process() I just did frame +=1 and now it's adding 1 every frame. which is what I need. In my old python code, when I used a move, it would set a state to attacking, then it would set the frame to 0, and would then play that animation and not let you move until the frame counter hit a certain amount. so I guess I got it now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GODOT - Full Attack Animation Not Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477874/godot-full-attack-animation-not-playing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make animations with `AnimatedSprite`. You have my blessing. `AnimatedSprite` is there to be used. And "I was told so" is not a good reason not to.

Also, `AnimatedSprite` vs `AnimationPlayer` and `AnimationTree` is not an either or. Yes, there are somethings for which you would need `AnimationPlayer` and `AnimationTree`, however you can always have the `AnimationPlayer` trigger an `AnimatedSprite` animation. In fact, `AnimationPlayer` can call any method (and `AnimationTree` will control the `AnimationPlayer`). Thus, any work done with `AnimatedSprite` is not wasted.

---

Calling `set_physics_process` will enable or disable `_physics_process`. And similarly `set_process` enables or disables `_process`. However, if you have a the method then it is enabled by default. Thus, you only need to enable them if you disabled them.

---

We can compress a lot of your `_physics_process` code:

```
func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var walking_speed := (
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") -
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    )
    anim.flip_h = walking_speed < 0
    var velocity := Vector2(walking_speed, 0)
    move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
```

The line `anim.flip_h = walking_speed < 0` will be setting `flip_h` to `true` when `walking_speed` is negative, and to `false` otherwise.

And we are setting `walking_speed` based on `get_action_strength` will return a number between `0` and `1` that represents how strongly the action is pressed. Which also means that if they are mapped to a joystick or similar, this gives you sensitivity support.

If you prefer to not have that sensitivity, `sign` will do:

```
    var walking_speed := sign(
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") -
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    )
```

---

With `KinematicBody2D` you would have to handle gravity. Basically give it some downwards velocity.

```
var gravitational_acceleration := 100 # pixels per second squared
var falling_speed := 0

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    falling_speed += gravitational_acceleration * delta
    var walking_speed := (
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") -
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    )
    anim.flip_h = walking_speed < 0
    var velocity := Vector2(walking_speed, falling_speed)
    move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
```

However, it is better to implement gravity with `move_and_slide`:

```
var gravitational_acceleration := 100 # pixels per second squared
var falling_speed := 0

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    falling_speed += gravitational_acceleration * delta
    var walking_speed := (
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") -
        Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    )
    anim.flip_h = walking_speed < 0
    var velocity := Vector2(walking_speed, falling_speed)
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    falling_speed = velocity.y
```

*I have removed the multiplication with `delta` at the end because `move_and_slide` does that internally. That is, it takes a velocity not a displacement.*

This way the `falling_speed` will not keep growing out of control.

You can also add an up vector (so Godot knows what is a ceiling, what is a floor, and what is a wall), and then you can check `is_on_ceiling`, `is_on_floor` and `is_on_wall`.

*Also, you can tell `move_and_slide` that the `floor_max_angle` is `0`, so it does not slide (nothing counts as a slope, only perfectly horizontal floors are floors), if that is what you want.*

---

And, of course, the animation.

If you are going to use an `AnimationTree`, I suggest to set the root as an `AnimationNodeStateMachine`. Then, from code, you can get the state machine playback object, like this:

```
var state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")
```

You can tell it you want it to go to a different state, like this:

```
state_machine.travel("name_of_some_state")
```

And you can ask it what the current state is with:

```
var state:String = state_machine.get_current_node()
```

You can, for example have an "idle" state in your state machine, and an "attacking" state in your state machine, with a transition from "idle" to "attacking", and another transition from "attacking" to "idle", but that one set to transition "at the end". *You can, of course, have other states.* Then use the current state (from `get_current_node`) to figure out what the player can do.

*With an `AnimationPlayer` you can check what is the `current_animation` and `is_playing`; you can also connect the `"animation_finished"` signal. With an `AnimatedSrite` you can check what is the current `animation` and whether or not it is `playing`; you can also connect the `"animation_finished"` signal.*

Comment: I'll note this and look at it when I feel confident to optimize my code. I really don't want to copy this because I don't understand really anything I'm looking at right now lol. Thank you and I appreciate it, but I need to try to get my bearings on something simple first before I start trying to throw my hat in the ring on this.